# Click a left/right button to display different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im working on a site and i want to add this next part where you can click left and right buttons to go through different work. There would be an image, a title, a paragraph and then a button. When you click a left or right arrow on the right or left it would swipe through different work.

See this image as to see the design of what im trying to do.

[image: Here is the image]

Im not sure what would be the best way to attack this. Some hid the current div and present the new div when the arrow is clicked. I'd be happy with just 3 different divs to swipe through. And when you click a arrow the current div will fade out quickly and the new div will fade in.

** would also need to be responsive** maybe at mobile you can swip insead of buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't reinvent the wheel**, someone may post a slick response that may work. But if you are creating elements with a degree of sophistication, it is better to use a library that has solved many of the issues that your own implementation either will not have time to handle or won't find any of these issues until later on. /endrant

```
Try any fine library off of github

[Unslider][1] 

[GlideJS][2]
```

Comment: Thats what i was looking for just didnt know what to search for. couldnt find anything. Thanks

Comment: just type in the component name ("slider","image gallery", "endless scroll", "notifications", "date picker") and pick the library with the most stars on github, for future issues. It will never fail you.